# Transform my good old mac pro in a HDD box to be connected with my new iMac

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, imac, mac-pro

I've just bough a new machine, 21,5 ", late 2013. And I would like to know if its possible to turn my old mac pro late 2006 in a HDD box to be connected via UB3 or thunderbolt to my iMac?
Then I could keep all my files in the same state if I can say.

Answer (score 1):

You could use it running in **Target Disk Mode**

From http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725

If you have two Mac computers with FireWire or Thunderbolt ports, you can connect them so that one of them appears as an external hard disk on the other. This is called “target disk mode.”

1. Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable.
2. Start up the computer to be used as a disk in target disk mode:

   - If the computer is off, start it up while holding down the T key.
   - If the computer is on, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Startup Disk, and then click Target Disk Mode.

     When the computer has started up, a disk icon appears on the desktop of the other computer.
3. Transfer files by dragging them to and from the disk.
4. Eject the disk by dragging its icon to the Trash.
   While you drag, the Trash icon changes to an Eject icon.
5. On the computer you used as a disk, push the power button to shut it down, and then disconnect the cable.

Comment: Hi thanx a lot I will checked this out and back asap with feedback. I hope that's can keep a quiet good speed transfer for my files 'cause I'm working in audio world. Thanx !

Comment: You won't get a great deal of speed from the transfer, Firewire 400 is slightly slower than USB 2 - 400 vs 480Mb. Thunderbolt RAID would be the way to go really.

Comment: yep you're right, but this good old mac pro have a FW 800, so I can use the adapter to thunderbolt. I'm actually waiting to it then I will try it out.